# hidden input wont pass to database

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to date when something is submitting into my database.  This isn't working, no errors, just puts nothing into the database.

I have in the body...

```
<input type="hidden" id="thedate" name="DateModified">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDate()
{    
 var date = new Date();
 var day = date.getDate();
 var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
 var year = date.getFullYear();

 if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
 if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

 var today = month + "/" + day+ "/" + year;

 document.getElementById('thedate').value = today;
}
</script>
```

Then, at the bottom of the page before `</body>` I have...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
GetDate();
</script>
```

The form is...

```
<form method="POST" action="blabla.asp">
```

Everything else in my form goes to the database, just not the date.

Comment: There are a couple issues with this. First, you're not respecting timezone differences, which means you might have people inserting from the future/past. Not sure if this matters to you, but I'd recommend a simple Date().toISOString(), which preserves all the information you might need. The other thing is you could instead add this function to your submit button, and just have it pass the arguments along with an ajax call instead of `action=`

Comment: which rdms are you using ?? Also, you need to share your sql query as well and also share your complete `form` code

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive so you have declare function as getDate() while calling as GetDate();

thats why its not being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

- Change GetDate() to getDate()
- Make sure that you are reading "DateModified" in the server instead of "thedate" field.
- I'd also suggest that you get the timestamp (UTC) in the server instead from the client's browser. Anyone can post to the url using tools like postman etc and send in bogus timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your bottom script looks like below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   GetDate(); // wrong
   getDate(); // right
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Vasi, that was it.  Stupid Case Sensitive ! ! !

Comment: @Jim If this answer helped you, you might want to upvote or accept it. Furthermore take a look at kebin's answer below. He answered this 5 minutes earlier.